# My output isn't printing out the same value when passing through variables in my function

Tags: python, function, sum, output, addition

I couldn't understand why my code isnt printing as it should compared to another code I have written.

```
def total(a, b):
  if a != b:
    sum = a+b
  else:
    sum = (a+b)*2
```

the code above only print None when i pass through values whereas the code below print the desired results. Can I please get an explanation to why that happens? thanks a lot in advance.

```
def sum_double(a, b):
  sum = a + b
  if a == b:
    sum = sum * 2
  return sum
```

Comment: You don't return anything from the first code.

Comment: The first code don't return.

Comment: Functions return None if they don't explicitly return.

Comment: You forgot to return `sum` in the first function, so it implicitly returns `None`.  Didn't you see the missing `return` statement?  It's a glaring difference.

Answer (score 0):

In the first function, you don’t return a value. In that case, Python return `None` automatically.

Also: you use the variable name `sum`, which is also a built-in function. Don’t do that, because you won’t be able to call `sum()` within the same scope.